# OSX gesture events not called in Spritekit SKScene

Tags: macos, events, gesture

I am trying to generalize a working IOS app to Mac OSX using Trackpad gestures and normal mouse events.

The simple mouse down and mouse dragged is working as expected but the more relevant scrollWheel and trackpad gestures do not get executed.

From IOS I know that my scene needs to declare a delegate protocol for gesture recognizers, but on OSX, shouldn't this be the normal NSReceiver behavior?

I did try all old tips including playing around with the system preferences for the trackpad, so far without success.

If anyone is aware of a Xcode sample project for trackpad, a link would be great as well.

```
#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
@interface MAJMainScene() <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>
#else
@interface MAJMainScene()
#endif


#if TARGET_OS_IPHONE
...
#else
#pragma mark OSX Event Handling
- (void)mouseDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
   NSLog(@"mouseDown");    //this method is called
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
   return YES;   // debug breakpoint never gets called
}

//reading apples documentation, the following method shouldn't be necessary for high-level trackpad gestures, I tried anyway.
- (BOOL)setAcceptsTouchEvents {
    return YES;  // debug breakpoint never gets called
}

- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent{
     NSLog(@"Scroll");    //this method is NOT called
 }

- (void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog (@"Magnification value is %f", [event magnification]);  //NOT called
}

- (void)rotateWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"rotate");     //NOT called
}

- (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"swipe");    //NOT called
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just answered a similar question at: [Detect scroll wheel movement and direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20857969/detect-scroll-wheel-movement-and-direction/20892854#20892854)

In your case, you can just forward all the other events to your scene, like so:

```
@implementation SKView(ScrollTouchForwarding)

- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self.scene scrollWheel:event];
}

- (void)magnifyWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self.scene magnifyWithEvent:event];
}

- (void)rotateWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self.scene rotateWithEvent:event];
}

- (void)swipeWithEvent:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self.scene swipeWithEvent:event];
}

@end
```