# Detect scroll wheel movement and direction

Tags: objective-c, macos, sprite-kit, mousewheel

I'm programming a game using the new Sprite-Kit framework and want to use the mouse scroll wheel to change the player's gun. First of all i want to handle when the scroll wheel moves. I tried the following method, from the [Cocoa Event Handling Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSResponder/scrollWheel%3a)

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    NSLog(@"SCROOOOOOOLL iN MOVeMENT");
}
```

*Result*: nothing, i didn't handle when i moved the mouse wheel.

Any idea of how can i handle this event ?

UPDATE: 
I saw two answers talking about class derivative from NSResponder or NSView but my class derives from SKScene, i'm programming using the Sprite-kit framework and obj-c doesn't allow multiple inheritance.

Here the class definition:

```
    #import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@interface OpcionesMenu : SKScene

@end
```

Comment: In what class did you add a `scrollWheel:` method?

Comment: Make sure your class derives, directly or indirectly, from NSResponder to be able to override scrollWheel:

Comment: I think thats no possible with my class deriving from SKScene. I'm pretty lost.

Comment: @JorgeVegaSánchez: can you clarify on which platform you need that (iOS or OS X)?

Answer (score 6):

Even though `SKScene` derives from `NSResponder`, it isn't a direct recipient of AppKit events. Rather, the `SKView` (derived from `NSView`/`UIView`) that houses the scene handles the events. You can observe this by setting a breakpoint on your scene's `mouseDown` method:

```
 -[TWTMyScene mouseDown:]
 -[SKView mouseDown:] ()
 -[NSWindow sendEvent:] ()
 -[NSApplication sendEvent:] ()
 -[NSApplication run] ()
  NSApplicationMain ()
```

So you can subclass `SKView` and forward the `scrollWheel` event yourself. Or, if you like living dangerously, you can just paste this category at the end of any of your code and it will take care of it for you:

```
@implementation SKView(ScrollTouchForwarding)

- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)event {
    [self.scene scrollWheel:event];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 2):

I think that could help:

```
- (void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    [super scrollWheel:theEvent];

    NSLog(@"user scrolled %f horizontally and %f vertically", [theEvent deltaX], [theEvent deltaY]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but I was having this exact problem with a collection view. So I have a `NSScrollView` that contains a `NSCollectionView` and some other views such as labels and buttons.

Anyway I wanted to get the collection view to be able to scroll horizontally and parent scroll view to to scroll vertically. I achieved this by storing and comparing the `deltaX` and `deltaY` values.

I made a custom scroll view class and set it to the collection view's scroll view.

Here is the header code:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface CustomCollectionScrollView : NSScrollView {

    // Current scroll position.
    CGFloat positionAxisX;
    CGFloat positionAxisY;
}

@end
```

And here is the implementation code:

```
#import "CustomCollectionScrollView.h"

@implementation CustomCollectionScrollView

/// DRAW RECT METHOD ///

-(void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect {
    [super drawRect:dirtyRect];

    positionAxisX = 0.0;
    positionAxisY = 0.0;
}

/// SCROLL METHODS ///

-(void)scrollWheel:(NSEvent *)theEvent {

    // Move the parent scroll view scroll view if the user is
    // scrolling vertically otherwise move the collection scroll view.

    if ((theEvent.deltaX == positionAxisX) && (theEvent.deltaY != positionAxisY)) {
        [self.nextResponder scrollWheel:theEvent];
    } else if ((theEvent.deltaX != positionAxisX) && (theEvent.deltaY == positionAxisY)) {
        [super scrollWheel:theEvent];
    }

    // Update the current position values.
    positionAxisX = theEvent.deltaX;
    positionAxisY = theEvent.deltaY;
}

@end
```

Answer (score -1):

I don't know much about SpriteKit, but I see that there is an `SKView` class that is a subclass of `NSView`.  I would guess that you should subclass `SKView` and put your `scrollWheel:` method there.

Comment: Both, SKView and SKScene are derived from UIResponder (and if you say there's an AppKit variant too, this probably applies to that too). The OP however already showed that his class derives from SKScene.

Comment: @MikeLischke: I know he said that his class derives from SKScene, but using only that class isn't going to work.  Scroll wheel events go to views.

Answer (score -3):

SKScene is part of SpriteKit which is an iOS framework, not an AppKit framework. Hence there is no scroll wheel handling at all (and no NSResponder (but UIResponder) in the inheritance chain). You can only work with touch events in the sprite kit.

Comment: SpriteKit is in OS X as of 10.9.  And as a matter of fact `SKScene` does derive from `NSResponder`, though I don't think that helps.

Comment: Can you point me to a link for the OSX variant? All I can find is the iOS docs: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I don't know a web link, but you can use the documentation viewer in Xcode 5.  Browse the OS X 10.9 doc set, and under Media Layer you'll find SpriteKit.